# Extend interface from other package

Tags: typescript

I have the interfaces `IProduct` and `ICategory` which are defined in some other file, which I can't edit.

```
interface IProduct {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}
interface ICategory {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  products: IProduct[],
}
```

How I can extend IProduct so it also contains another property price? so that ICategory should be like:

```
interface ICategory {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  products: {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    price: number
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show, how `IProduct` and `ICategory` are embedded in the other file? is the file a module, is it a declaration file (`.d.ts`), are they contained in ambient module declarations like `declare module "xxx" {}`?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you can't edit `IProduct` and `ICategory` directly. You can simply **repeat** the `IProduct` interface and add properties to it. Add a property to the Interface and it will work as expected

`file out of your reach`:

```js
interface IProduct {
  id: number,
  name: string,
}
```

`your file`:

```js
import { IProduct } from 'someApi';

interface IProduct {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  price: number // new property
}

const product: IProduct = {
  id: '1241534',
  name: 'Carrot',
  price: 2.0
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new `ICategoryProduct` type like as follow:

```
type ICategoryProduct = {
  price: number
} & IProduct
```

Then use the type in `ICategory` interface:

```
interface ICategory {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  products: ICategoryProduct
}
```

Or you can define your `products` type in `ICategory`:

```
interface ICategory {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  products: {
    price: number
  } & IProduct
}
```

But, I think `products` need to be an array, then `ICategory` interface will be like:

```
interface ICategory {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  products: Array<{
    price: number
  } & IProduct>
}
```

Comment: IProduct and ICategory are defined in some other file, which I can't edit. Secondly ICategory contains a large list of props, which I don't want to write again. Just want to extend it in a way that category.products may also contain price prop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something simpler. Can you just make another interface like this

```
interface IProductWithPrice extends IProduct {
    price: number;
}
```